# What kind of food did Jesus eat?

Tags: luke

Luke 9:16 Taking the five loaves and the two fish and looking up to heaven, he gave thanks and broke them. Then he gave them to the disciples to distribute to the people.

Besides bread and fish, what common foods did people eat at that time in that area?

Answer (score 1):

What Food did Yeshua (Jesus) eat?

1. “Fig” (Tenah , תאנה) [Mark 11:12-14] “Jesus was hungry. 13 Seeing in the distance a fig tree in leaf, he went to find out if it had any fruit. When he reached it, he found nothing but leaves, because it was not the season for figs. 14 Then he said to the tree, “May no one ever eat fruit from you again.”